# No water in line to ice maker

Tags: ice-maker, ice

I just installed a new valve for my ice maker/water dispenser for my Roper refrigerator that I bought used.  The water comes out of the water dispenser, but there is no water in the line to the ice maker and the ice maker is not making ice.  Am I wrong to think that there should be water going through that line constantly or does it only get triggered at times when it is needed to fill the trays?  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: How long has it been running?

Comment: About 12 hours.

Comment: Have you tried shutting off the valve, disconnecting the line from the fridge, putting the end in a bucket and opening the valve?

Answer (score 1):

Ice makers typically have their own electrically-actuated valves. The system may need to cycle a few times to purge the air.

There may also be a manual purge process, depending on the model. See if you can find your owner's manual online by model number.

In the meantime, you could fill the ice trays with water from a container to be sure the system is functioning. It should eject the ice after a while.

Comment: Thank you.  I should be able to find a manual online.  I will check that and then check it again when I get home to see if anything has changed.  I will have my wife fill the trays with water in the meantime.  Thanks!

Comment: I found a manual.  It states to wait 24 hours for ice production to begin.  Does that sound right?

Comment: I don't know why not. It must take a few cycles to purge the air. Each cycle may be 4 hours or more.